# Exporting an image results in changing pixels value

Tags: graphics, export, image

When exporting an image from the Mathematica and comparing it to the same image in the code using `ImageData[Img,Byte]`, it results into 2 different vectors , so what's wrong with the exporting method ?! and, is there any another way of exporting an image without using `Export[ ]` method ?

```
CarImg = Import["D:\Images\MonaLisa.jpg"]; 

X=ImageData[CarImg,Byte]; 

Y=ImageData[Import[Export["Image.jpg",CarImg]],Byte];
```

***Values of the Original Image:***
{{{124, 128, 98}, {80, 89, 62}, {87, 100, 81}, {90, 109, 91}, {87, 109,89}, {75, 92, 68}, {82, 94, 64}, {92, 100, 66}, {78, 98, 87}, {97, 118, 101}, {88, 114, 89}}}

***Values of the Exported Image:***
{{{116, 128, 118}, {69, 81, 69}, {89, 99, 88}, {94, 105, 89}, {99, 107, 92}, {79, 88, 69}, {82, 94, 74}, {87, 101, 78}, {83, 97,74}, {102, 120, 96}}}

Values aren't identical. I want to preserve the values of the original image when exporting.

Comment: Please post a MWE. How did you compare the image you exported with the image in the notebook?  Images displayed in notebook are raster format, but image on disk can be any other binary format such as png or jpg etc... when you export an image from the notebook to a file and give it a format, Mathematica converts the image to that format. So you can't expect the bits in the file to be the same as displayed inside the notebook.

Comment: So, is there  a way of  reserve the values of the original image during exporting (for example: to the desktop). So when i import the image again in another notebook i get the same original values ? Thanks.

Comment: Again, your description of the problem is not clear. You are not showing all the steps. Was the original image imported from an image file first, then you exported it back again? Or it was a Mathematica Graphics you created inside the notebook? Please show all the code you used so that the issue is made more clear.

Comment: `CarImg = Import["D:\Images\MonaLisa.jpg"];
X=ImageData[CarImg,Byte];

Y=ImageData[Import[Export["Image.jpg",CarImg]],Byte];`


This is the code. X and Y aren't identical as i assume.

Comment: Ok, this is more clear. Please post the above comment in the question itself, so it can be more easily seen.

Comment: Ok and thanks for your replies.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to upload your `MonaLisa.jpg` to an image host?

Comment: JPEG encoding uses lossy compression, so you will not generally get back the same data when you decode it.

Comment: right, even though you started out with a jpg, it is highly unlikely you will get the same jpg when you re-compress it.  Use something lossless like tiff.

Comment: [The documentation for JPEG](https://wolfr.am/w89HLTij) clearly states that *"Uses a lossy compression method"* and *"resolution of 8 bits per color"* so changes are expected. Your question may be put [on-hold](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake of not reading the documentation and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution which is saving the image as ".png" instead of ".jpg" to preserve it's original quality.

Comment: Sounds like this is related to JPG being a lossy image format and PNG being a lossless image format.